Suggest you set the sbotools REPO setting to https://github.com/Ponce/slackbuilds.git
Just got Slackware on my machine and I am little bit confused in setting up SlackBuild.
I attempted these commands (after downloading package):
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads# tar xzvf sbotools.tar.gz
sbotools/
sbotools/sbotools.info
sbotools/slack-desc
sbotools/README
sbotools/sbotools.SlackBuild
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads# cd sbotools
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# . ./sbotools.info
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# wget $DOWNLOAD
--2024-10-12 23:13:09--  https://pink-mist.github.io/sbotools/downloads/sbotools-2.7.tar.gz
Resolving pink-mist.github.io (pink-mist.github.io)... 2606:50c0:8003::153, 2606:50c0:8001::153, 2606:50c0:8000::153, ...
Connecting to pink-mist.github.io (pink-mist.github.io)|2606:50c0:8003::153|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 45833 (45K) [application/gzip]
Saving to: ‘sbotools-2.7.tar.gz’

sbotools-2.7.tar.gz 100%[===================>]  44.76K   243KB/s    in 0.2s    

2024-10-12 23:13:10 (243 KB/s) - ‘sbotools-2.7.tar.gz’ saved [45833/45833]

root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# md5sum $(basename $DOWNLOAD)
ddf4b174fa29839564d7e784ff142581  sbotools-2.7.tar.gz
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# echo $MD5SUM
ddf4b174fa29839564d7e784ff142581
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# echo $MD5SUM
ddf4b174fa29839564d7e784ff142581
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# sh sbotools.SlackBuild
sbotools-2.7/
sbotools-2.7/sboclean
sbotools-2.7/man5/
sbotools-2.7/man5/sbotools.conf.5
sbotools-2.7/sboremove
sbotools-2.7/sboupgrade
sbotools-2.7/sbofind
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/t/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/t/SBO-Lib.t
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/t/versions.t
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/Changes
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/Sort/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/Sort/Versions.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/App/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/App/Snap.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/App/Remove.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/App.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Readme.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Build.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Tree.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Pkgs.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Repo.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Info.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Util.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/lib/SBO/Lib/Download.pm
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/Makefile.PL
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/MANIFEST
sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/README
sbotools-2.7/README
sbotools-2.7/sboinstall
sbotools-2.7/man1/
sbotools-2.7/man1/sbocheck.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sboconfig.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sboclean.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sbofind.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sboupgrade.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sboinstall.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sboremove.1
sbotools-2.7/man1/sbosnap.1
sbotools-2.7/sbocheck
sbotools-2.7/sboconfig
sbotools-2.7/sbosnap
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for SBO::Lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/SBO/App.pm blib/lib/SBO/App.pm
cp lib/Sort/Versions.pm blib/lib/Sort/Versions.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Info.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Info.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Readme.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Readme.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Download.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Download.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Build.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Build.pm
cp lib/SBO/App/Remove.pm blib/lib/SBO/App/Remove.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Tree.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Tree.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Util.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Util.pm
cp lib/SBO/App/Snap.pm blib/lib/SBO/App/Snap.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Pkgs.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Pkgs.pm
cp lib/SBO/Lib/Repo.pm blib/lib/SBO/Lib/Repo.pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl5.40.0" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/SBO-Lib.t ... ok   
t/versions.t .. ok     
All tests successful.
Files=2, Tests=97,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.01 sys +  0.07 cusr  0.02 csys =  0.11 CPU)
Result: PASS
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/App.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Info.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Readme.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Download.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Build.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Tree.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Util.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Pkgs.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Repo.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/App/Remove.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/SBO/App/Snap.pm
Installing /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/share/perl5/Sort/Versions.pm
Appending installation info to /tmp/SBo/package-sbotools/usr/lib64/perl5/perllocal.pod

Slackware package maker, version 3.14159265.

Searching for symbolic links:

No symbolic links were found, so we won't make an installation script.
You can make your own later in ./install/doinst.sh and rebuild the
package if you like.

This next step is optional - you can set the directories in your package
to some sane permissions. If any of the directories in your package have
special permissions, then DO NOT reset them here!

Would you like to reset all directory permissions to 755 (drwxr-xr-x) and
directory ownerships to root.root ([y]es, [n]o)? n

Creating Slackware package:  /tmp/sbotools-2.7-noarch-1_SBo.tgz

./
install/
install/slack-desc
usr/
usr/doc/
usr/doc/sbotools-2.7/
usr/doc/sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/
usr/doc/sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/Changes
usr/doc/sbotools-2.7/SBO-Lib/README
usr/doc/sbotools-2.7/sbotools.SlackBuild
usr/man/
usr/man/man1/
usr/man/man1/sbocheck.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sboclean.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sboconfig.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sbofind.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sboinstall.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sboremove.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sbosnap.1.gz
usr/man/man1/sboupgrade.1.gz
usr/man/man5/
usr/man/man5/sbotools.conf.5.gz
usr/sbin/
usr/sbin/sbocheck
usr/sbin/sboclean
usr/sbin/sboconfig
usr/sbin/sbofind
usr/sbin/sboinstall
usr/sbin/sboremove
usr/sbin/sbosnap
usr/sbin/sboupgrade
usr/share/
usr/share/perl5/
usr/share/perl5/SBO/
usr/share/perl5/SBO/App/
usr/share/perl5/SBO/App.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/App/Remove.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/App/Snap.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Build.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Download.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Info.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Pkgs.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Readme.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Repo.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Tree.pm
usr/share/perl5/SBO/Lib/Util.pm
usr/share/perl5/Sort/
usr/share/perl5/Sort/Versions.pm

Slackware package /tmp/sbotools-2.7-noarch-1_SBo.tgz created.

root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# /sbin/installpkg /tmp/sbotools-2.7-noarch-1_SBo.tgz
Verifying package sbotools-2.7-noarch-1_SBo.tgz.
Installing package sbotools-2.7-noarch-1_SBo.tgz:
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
# sbotools (ports-like interface to slackbuilds.org)
#
# sbotools is a set of perl scripts providing a ports-like automation
# interface to slackbuilds.org. Its features include requirement
# handling and the ability to handle 32-bit and compat32 builds on
# multilib x86_64 systems.
#
# https://pink-mist.github.io/sbotools/
#
Package sbotools-2.7-noarch-1_SBo.tgz installed.
root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# sbosnap fetch
Pulling SlackBuilds tree...
Unsupported Slackware version: 15.0+
Suggest you set the sbotools REPO setting to https://github.com/Ponce/slackbuilds.git

root@darkstar:/home/live/Downloads/sbotools# 

Is sbotools an outdated application? What is the proper way to add SlackBuilds to my machine? Thank you so much for any help.

Not really a solution, but I did find that sbopkg appears to function: https://sbopkg.org/downloads.php
